# Appium test launch error + remotewebdriver

Tags: android, selenium, webdriver, remotewebdriver, appium

Getting below error when running an Appium test

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: A                   session is either terminated or not started (Original error: Command failed: 'adb' is not    recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 13.51 seconds
Build info: version: '2.30.0', revision: 'dc1ef9c', time: '2013-02-19 00:15:27'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_41'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.new      Instance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:151)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:111)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:129)
    at tests.AppiumTest.main(AppiumTest.java:29)
```

Steps followed-

1.ANDROID_HOME env set to sdk path(E:\softwares\android\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130729\sdk)
2.Started Appium server using Appium.exe
3.Selenium standalone server started

Code:-

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.setCapability("app-package", "com.android.example.spinner");
    caps.setCapability("browserName", "");
    caps.setCapability("device", "Android");
    caps.setCapability("app-activity",
            "com.android.example.spinner.SpinnerActivity");
    caps.setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);
    caps.setCapability("version", "4.3");
    caps.setCapability("device ID", "5554");
    caps.setCapability("app",
            "E:\\eclipse\\SpinnerActivity\\bin\\SpinnerActivity.apk");

    RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(
            "http://localhost:4723/wd/hub/"), caps);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following measures resolved the issue,
1. The emulator was taking time to launch, need to wait till it is fully launched
2. Path of PLATFORM_TOOLS and TOOLS added to %PATH% env variable